# yarn install throws github.com[1: 127.0.0.1]: errno=Connection refused

Tags: git, proxy, hadoop-yarn, http-proxy

When I executed `yarn install`, it throws:

```
error Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/frozeman/bignumber.js-nolookahead.git
Directory: /Users/pro/eth/hello-snap
Output:
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 127.0.0.1]: errno=Connection refused
github.com[1: ::1]: errno=Connection refused
```

I checked `/etc/hosts`, there was no `127.0.0.1 github.com` or `::1 github.com`.

And also I removed http.proxy by `git config --global --unset http.proxy`.

It bothered me a whole day  Does anyone know how it comes?